# Реализация функции с помощью алгоритма Стаи серых Волков

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, дискретная-математика

Задавал вопрос по этому же примеру, но с реализацией по генетическому алгоритму. Сейчас мне нужно реализовать этот же пример, только с помощью алгоритма Стаи серых Волков. Есть у кого-то примеры с использованием данного алгоритма?
Толковой инфы в браузере не нашел(помимо английской ноуледж базы, там она есть, но особой конкретизации не нашёл, возможно что плохо искал)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задача учебная? В таком случае очень будет полезно спросить преподавателя о методичке или какой-нибудь литературе. Если таковая имеется - напишите плиз, мне самому очень интересно про алгоритм почитать... И мне кажется, этот алгоритм является генетическим алгоритмом (как я говорил в вашем другом вопросе, генетический алгоритм это не конкретный алгоритм, а целый класс алгоритмов).

Comment: Вот, нашёл интересную статью по теме: [Алгоритм стаи серых волков](https://ores.su/media/filer_public/0b/44/0b44d730-0ecb-4bc4-9aef-ca19364a3891/7_algoritm_stai_serykh_volkov_gwo_dlia_zadach_optimizatsii.pdf), будет полезно.